# async problem array empty nodejs mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, async-await

i want to obtain from an array of IDs that come in the req.body the name and price of each of the products and save it in a new model (payment), for this I go through each product and look for its id in the db (Product.findById ) and I save as an object in arrayProducts what I need (name and price), but the newPayment is created before the arrayProducts is finished filling and I create it empty, as I could do so that the newPayment is created after the forEach of the products finish?

```
router.post('/new/payment', async (req, res) => {

    const date = Date.now();

    const { amount, clientId, products, services, officeId } = req.body;

    var arrayProducts = [];

    products.forEach(function (product) {
        var productFound = {};

        Product.findById(product, function (err, result) {
            if (err) {
                res.status(404).send({ error: "Oh uh, something went wrong", err: err });
            }
            else {
                productFound = { name: result.name, price: result.price };
                arrayProducts.push(productFound);
                console.log(arrayProducts);
            }
        })
    });
    console.log(arrayProducts);

    const newPayment = new Payment({ amount, clientId, products: arrayProducts, services, officeId, date });
    await newPayment.save((err) => {
        if (err) {
            res.status(404).send({ error: "Oh uh, something went wrong", err: err });
        }
        else {
            res.status(201).send({ status: "Payment successful", id: newPayment._id });
        }

    });;
});
```

Comment: You need to do some reading about non-blocking, asynchronous operations in node.js.  Your `Product.findById()` is non-blocking and asynchronous which means its callback is called LONG after your entire route handler has finished executing and certainly after the  `console.log(arrayProducts);` and all the code that comes after that.

Comment: What you should probably do is change `products.forEach()` to `for (let product of products) { ... }`, use the Promise interface for your database and use `await` on that promise so you can properly sequence your operations and when the last one is done, THEN execute the rest of the code.  Alternatively, you could collect all the promises and use `Promise.all()` to track when they were all done.

Comment: FYI, if you put unique `console.log()` statements in the various parts of your code (before the loop, inside the loop and after the loop), you will see the flawed order of execution.  This is something you should learn how to do yourself as a basic debugging step.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do some reading about non-blocking, asynchronous operations in node.js. Your `Product.findById()` is non-blocking and asynchronous which means its callback is called LONG after your entire route handler has finished executing and certainly after the `console.log(arrayProducts);` and all the code that comes after that.

Since you want to do N requests from your database and you just want to know when they are all done, the most efficient way to do that would be to use the Promise interface for your database, collect an array of promises from all the DB operations and then use `Promise.all()` to inform when they are all done.

This is what I would suggest:

```
router.post('/new/payment', async (req, res) => {

    const date = Date.now();
    const { amount, clientId, products, services, officeId } = req.body;
    try {
        const allProducts = await Promise.all(products.map(async (product) => {
            const item = await Product.findById(product);
            return {name: item.name, price: item.price};
        }));
        const newPayment = new Payment({ amount, clientId, products: allProducts, services, officeId, date });
        await newPayment.save();
        res.status(201).send({ status: "Payment successful", id: newPayment._id });
    } catch(err) {
        res.status(404).send({ error: "Oh uh, something went wrong", err: err });
    }
});
```

Other things that are missing from this code are:

1. Validating input values for `amount, clientId, products, services, officeId` and sending appropriate errors if any of them are missing or invalid.
2. What to do if a product is specified that is not found in your database?
3. A 404 error may not be appropriate if you're getting a database error (which would probably be a 500 error).

Comment: @nahuelmuñoz - Are you still here?  I'm trying to teach you how to program this type of code in nodejs, but you seem to have disappeared.